# sql count by room type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following table structure and i want count all room types from Reservation table.
I want to have something like this:
Roomtype :double 3
         :simple 5 
It is possible to make this?

[image]

I only managed to count all rooms from reservation table

`SELECT  COUNT(Room_ID)AS NumarRezervari
FROM dbo.Reservation WHERE MONTH(Data_Check_in)=5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Room_Type, COUNT(*) AS NumarRezervari
FROM   dbo.Reservation re
JOIN   dbo.Room ro ON ro.RoomID = re.RoomID
JOIN   dbo.Room_Type rt ON rt.Room_Type_ID = ro.Room_Type_ID
WHERE  MONTH(re.Data_Check_in) = 5
GROUP  BY Room_Type
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `GROUP BY` clause and couple of joins, like this:

```
SELECT Room_Type, count(*) FROM Reservation rv
INNER JOIN Room rm ON rm.Room_ID = rv.Room_ID
INNER JOIN Room_Type rt ON rm.RoomType_ID = rt.RoomType_ID
GROUP BY Room_Type
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want a count of the amount of room types i think you can do something like this:

```
select count (Room_Type_Id) from Room_Type
inner join Room on Room.Room_Type_ID = Room_Type.RoomType_ID 
inner join Reservation on Reservation.Room_ID = Room.RoomID 
where ...
```